# Редактирование блоков в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, шаблоны

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть 2 блока на одной странице(1 блок со светлым фоном, 2 блок с тёмным фоном)Подскажите что нужно прописать в index.php , чтобы можно было редактировать каждый блок отдельно?

```
    <section id="bg-main">
    <div class="container">
        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 color-font-black position-top">
                    <?php the_content();?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="bg-advantage">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row title-row">
            <?php the_content();?><br>
        <div class="row content-row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <?php the_content();?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <?php the_content();?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <?php the_content();?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <?php the_content();?>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /row -->
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Редактировать css или html?

Comment: Я хочу редактировать контент в каждом из блоков

Comment: Что скажешь, ответ подходит или нет? Прокомментируй.

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую, тут есть два решения:

Необходимо зарегистрировать произвольные области, например:

```
<?php echo (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'имя фрейма', true)); ?>
```

и использовать их для своих нужд.

Если все это есть на каждой странице, то необходимо  создать облать для виджета в function.php, например:

```
$args_footer1 = array(
    'name'          => __( 'Позиция footer колонка 1', 'wob_theme' ),
        'id'            => 'wob_theme_foooter1',
    'description'   => 'Колонка с произвольным текстом',
        'class'         => 'col-md-3 col-sm-6 inner',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="%2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h4>',
    'after_title'   => '</h4>' ); 
register_sidebar($args_footer1);
```

и вызвать её, как нормальный человек в footer.php

```
 <?php if(!dynamic_sidebar("wob_theme_foooter1")): ?>
                                       <?php endif; ?>
```

Более подробное описание:

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets

https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields